# Show the error message of a type even if it is required and not provided?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validate to validate a form. The form has required fields and non-required fields. I was hoping you could help me figure out a way to show the error message of the type even when the field has not been provided in place of the default "required" message.

I have scoured the internet and it seems no one has ever tried to do what I want to do (I don't actually believe this, but I did not find the answer while scouring).

It would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "I was hoping you could help me figure out a way to show the error message of the type even when the field has not been provided in place of the default "required" message." what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

Click the 'options' tab and scroll down to 'messages'

Or, I believe the default action is to use the title attribute of the element you're validating for the error message.